# Shared_ptr is null on re-iteration in std::Vector

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, stdvector

I have the below program of an execution class which populates a map shown below

```
map<string,map<string,vector<StructAbsTypeObject>>>
```

Here I am making shared objects and assigning them which are valid during first check, but on second check shared_ptr returns null. I need to know the reason why. The code seems fine but don't know where is it going wrong.

```
//Code begins
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
  Test(int i):t(i) {
  }

private:
  int t;
};

class ConcTypeObject {
public:
  ConcTypeObject() {
  }

  ConcTypeObject(const ConcTypeObject& other) {
    m_ptr_Test = other.m_ptr_Test;
  }

  ConcTypeObject& operator=(const ConcTypeObject& other) {
    m_ptr_Test = other.m_ptr_Test;
  }

  void setTest(shared_ptr<Test> ptr) {
    cout << "setTest" << endl;
    m_ptr_Test = ptr;
  }

  shared_ptr<Test> getTest() {
    return m_ptr_Test;
  }

  bool isValid() {
    if(m_ptr_Test) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

private:
  shared_ptr<Test> m_ptr_Test;
};


class AbsTypeObject {
public:
  explicit AbsTypeObject(const string str) {
    m_str = str;
  }

  AbsTypeObject(const AbsTypeObject& other) {
    m_str = other.m_str;
    m_ptr_ConcTypeObject = other.m_ptr_ConcTypeObject;
  }

  AbsTypeObject& operator=(const AbsTypeObject& other) {
    m_str = other.m_str;
    m_ptr_ConcTypeObject = other.m_ptr_ConcTypeObject;
  }

  bool operator==(const AbsTypeObject& other) {
    if(m_str == other.m_str)
      return true;
    else 
      return false;  
  }

  void setConcTypeObject(shared_ptr<ConcTypeObject> ptr) {
    m_ptr_ConcTypeObject = ptr;
  }

  shared_ptr<ConcTypeObject> getConcTypeObject() {
    return m_ptr_ConcTypeObject;
  }

  bool isValid() {
    if(m_ptr_ConcTypeObject) {
      cout << "AbsTypeObject 1 " << endl;
      return m_ptr_ConcTypeObject->isValid();
    } else {
      cout << "AbsTypeObject 2 " << endl;
      return false;
    }
  }

private:
  string m_str;
  shared_ptr<ConcTypeObject> m_ptr_ConcTypeObject;
};


class StructAbsTypeObject {
  public:
    StructAbsTypeObject(const string str):m_AbsTypeObject(str) {
    }

    void SetAbsTypeObject(AbsTypeObject& id) {
      m_AbsTypeObject = id;
    }

    AbsTypeObject& GetAbsTypeObject() {
      return m_AbsTypeObject;
    }

    private:
    AbsTypeObject m_AbsTypeObject;
};


class Executor {
public:
    static Executor m_Executor;
    static Executor& get() {
        return m_Executor;
    }

    Executor() {
      StructAbsTypeObject sid(std::string("ABCD"));
      vector<StructAbsTypeObject> a_vecstid;
      a_vecstid.push_back(sid);
      m_executormap["ExecutorInterface"]["ExecutorName"] = a_vecstid;
    }

    void check() {
      for(auto outermap : m_executormap) {
        for(auto innermap : outermap.second) {
          for(auto vec_element: innermap.second) {
            if(vec_element.GetAbsTypeObject().isValid()) {
              cout << "PTR VALID" << endl;
            } else {
              cout << "PTR NOT Valid" << endl;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    void fillAbsTypeObject(AbsTypeObject &id) {
      shared_ptr<Test> ptr_test = make_shared<Test>(20);
      shared_ptr<ConcTypeObject> ptr_ConcTypeObject = make_shared<ConcTypeObject>();
      id.setConcTypeObject(ptr_ConcTypeObject);
      id.getConcTypeObject()->setTest(ptr_test);
    }

    void Init(AbsTypeObject id) {
      for(auto outermap : m_executormap) {
        for(auto innermap : outermap.second) {
          for(auto vec_element: innermap.second) {
            if(vec_element.GetAbsTypeObject() == id) {
              cout << "Id Equal" << endl;
              fillAbsTypeObject(id);
              vec_element.SetAbsTypeObject(id);
              if(vec_element.GetAbsTypeObject().isValid()) {
                cout << "PTR VALID" << endl;
              } else {
                cout << "PTR NOT Valid" << endl;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      check();
      }
    }

private:
  using executormap = map<string,map<string,vector<StructAbsTypeObject>>>;
  executormap m_executormap;
};

Executor Executor::m_Executor;

int main() 
{
  AbsTypeObject id(std::string("ABCD"));
  Executor::get().Init(id);

}
//Code Ends
```

The above code is completely compilable and Runnable. Currently I am getting the following output

```
//Output Begins

Id Equal
setTest
AbsTypeObject 1 
PTR VALID
AbsTypeObject 2 
PTR NOT Valid

//Output Ends
```

The PTR NOT VALID is output when check function is executed. Expecting output is 
PTR VALID in both cases.

Please let me know what is going wrong in the above code. I did try few things but did not work. If it does not work, what is the reason and what is the correct way to make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: This is a lot of code. Most people don’t have the time to read through this, you should really create a [mcve]

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are manually defining the copy constructor/assignment operators? The compiler will do that for you correctly (also see rule of five). Also, please enable warnings in your compiler, `AbsTypeObject& operator=(const AbsTypeObject& other)` claims to return a value but doesn't. That's undefined behavior. (Did I mention you should let the compiler generate that function because it will do it correctly?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your for loops:

```
  for(auto outermap : m_executormap) {
    for(auto innermap : outermap.second) {
      for(auto vec_element: innermap.second) {
```

You are using `auto` which defaults to a non-reference type so you are taking a copy of each element in the map/vector. Your changes are being applied to these temporary copies so are lost.

Simply change these to references to update the original lists:

```
  for(auto& outermap : m_executormap) {
    for(auto& innermap : outermap.second) {
      for(auto& vec_element: innermap.second) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Had not though of it. It's working now.